# How do i use package control to install packages in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, package-managers, package-control

I am using sublime text 2. I have successfully installed Package Control. Now that Package Control is installed, how do I go about installing packages?

Comment: you could try reading [the docs](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs)...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On a mac use `cmd + shift + p` (or click `Tools -> Command Palette`) and type `install` into the dropdown menu.  It should bring up `Package Control : Install Package`.  Hit enter and start typing the name of the package you wish to install.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + p` on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Installing Packages  on sublime3:

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`

Then type install and select first option Package control: `Install Package`

Then type `package name` and select the first option.

It will install in few moments.

Edit: The first option package name is `Package name` as pointed out in the comments below.

Then select `Installed packages` Syntax.

`View > Syntax > Babel > Javascript`